# Updating Multiple Tables using Node Postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, node-postgres

I have two tables, one stores customer orders and the other stores items in a specific order. I am trying to update both these tables at once as follows:

```
const updateCustOrder = 'UPDATE orders SET customer=$1, due_date=$2 WHERE order_id=$3';
const updateItem = 'UPDATE items SET order_id=$1, quantity=$2, cost=$3 WHERE item_id=$4';

Promise.all([
   pool.query(updateCustOrder, [customer, due_date, order_id]),
   pool.query(updateItem, [order_id, qty, cost, item_id])
]).then(function() {
   response.status(201).send('Successfully Updated');
}).catch(function (e) {
   response.status(500).send('Updated failed');
});
```

The attribute `order_id` is a primary key in the orders table and a foreign key in the items table. The problem I'm running into is that the values in the orders table get successfully updated, but the values in the items table are not updated.

Comment: Shouldn't you move `item_id` from the first array to the second where you do `updateItem`? As it looks like you missed id and got `WHERE item_id=undefinded`.

Comment: @DmitriiZolotuhin ah yes sorry that was just a typo, that error is not in my original code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into [knex](https://knexjs.org/) at all? It can help a lot with the more painful SQL tasks. Though, that doesn't exactly answer your question.

You could try using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

I admit I'm a bit rusty in Node. But, something like this should work:

```
async function sqlCalls() {
    const updateCustOrder = 'UPDATE orders SET customer=$1, due_date=$2 WHERE order_id=$3';
    const updateItem = 'UPDATE items SET order_id=$1, quantity=$2, cost=$3 WHERE item_id=$4';


    const first = await pool.query(updateCustOrder, [customer, due_date, order_id]);
    const second = await pool.query(updateItem, [order_id, qty, cost, item_id])

    // Use If/Else for error handling
}
```